# How to save One To Many relations in Sonata?

Tags: forms, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony4, sonata

I'm facing a problem in Symfony4 and Sonata Admin.

I have 3 entities : Orders, Product and Orders Product.
Here they are :

Orders :

```
class Orders
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateAdd;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateUpd;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $deliveryDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $internalReference;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $deliveryContactName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=15)
     */
    private $deliveryContactPhone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $deliveryAddress1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $deliveryAddress2;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $deliveryPostalCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $deliveryCountry;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $deliveryCompany;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $comment;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $deliveryCity;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\OrdersProduct", mappedBy="orders")
     */
    private $product;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->product = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDateAdd(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateAdd;
    }

    public function setDateAdd(\DateTimeInterface $dateAdd): self
    {
        $this->dateAdd = $dateAdd;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateUpd(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateUpd;
    }

    public function setDateUpd(\DateTimeInterface $dateUpd): self
    {
        $this->dateUpd = $dateUpd;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->deliveryDate;
    }

    public function setDeliveryDate(\DateTimeInterface $deliveryDate): self
    {
        $this->deliveryDate = $deliveryDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInternalReference(): ?string
    {
        return $this->internalReference;
    }

    public function setInternalReference(?string $internalReference): self
    {
        $this->internalReference = $internalReference;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryContactName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliveryContactName;
    }

    public function setDeliveryContactName(string $deliveryContactName): self
    {
        $this->deliveryContactName = $deliveryContactName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryContactPhone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliveryContactPhone;
    }

    public function setDeliveryContactPhone(string $deliveryContactPhone): self
    {
        $this->deliveryContactPhone = $deliveryContactPhone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryAddress1(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliveryAddress1;
    }

    public function setDeliveryAddress1(string $deliveryAddress1): self
    {
        $this->deliveryAddress1 = $deliveryAddress1;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryAddress2(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliveryAddress2;
    }

    public function setDeliveryAddress2(?string $deliveryAddress2): self
    {
        $this->deliveryAddress2 = $deliveryAddress2;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryPostalCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliveryPostalCode;
    }

    public function setDeliveryPostalCode(string $deliveryPostalCode): self
    {
        $this->deliveryPostalCode = $deliveryPostalCode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryCountry(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliveryCountry;
    }

    public function setDeliveryCountry(string $deliveryCountry): self
    {
        $this->deliveryCountry = $deliveryCountry;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryCompany(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliveryCompany;
    }

    public function setDeliveryCompany(?string $deliveryCompany): self
    {
        $this->deliveryCompany = $deliveryCompany;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?int
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(int $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getComment(): ?string
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }

    public function setComment(?string $comment): self
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryCity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliveryCity;
    }

    public function setDeliveryCity(string $deliveryCity): self
    {
        $this->deliveryCity = $deliveryCity;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
       if ($this->id)
           return $this->id." -".$this->internalReference;
       else
           return "";
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|OrdersProduct[]
     */
    public function getProduct(): Collection
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function addProduct(OrdersProduct $product): self
    {
        if (!$this->product->contains($product)) {
            $this->product[] = $product;
            $product->setOrders($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProduct(OrdersProduct $product): self
    {
        if ($this->product->contains($product)) {
            $this->product->removeElement($product);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($product->getOrders() === $this) {
                $product->setOrders(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Product :

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $priceWT;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $vat;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateAdd;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateUpd;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isDeleted;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPriceWT(): ?float
    {
        return $this->priceWT;
    }

    public function setPriceWT(float $priceWT): self
    {
        $this->priceWT = $priceWT;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVat(): ?float
    {
        return $this->vat;
    }

    public function setVat(float $vat): self
    {
        $this->vat = $vat;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateAdd(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateAdd;
    }

    public function setDateAdd(\DateTimeInterface $dateAdd): self
    {
        $this->dateAdd = $dateAdd;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateUpd(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateUpd;
    }

    public function setDateUpd(\DateTimeInterface $dateUpd): self
    {
        $this->dateUpd = $dateUpd;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory(): ?Category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsDeleted(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->isDeleted;
    }

    public function setIsDeleted(bool $isDeleted): self
    {
        $this->isDeleted = $isDeleted;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        if ($this->name)
            return $this->name;
        else
            return "Nouveau Produit";
    }

    public function calculatePriceTI()
    {
        return $this->priceWT * (1 + $this->vat);
    }
}
```

OrdersProduct :

```
class OrdersProduct
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Orders", inversedBy="product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $orders;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $priceWT;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getOrders(): ?Orders
    {
        return $this->orders;
    }

    public function setOrders(?Orders $orders): self
    {
        $this->orders = $orders;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProduct(): ?Product
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function setProduct(?Product $product): self
    {
        $this->product = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuantity(): ?int
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    public function setQuantity(int $quantity): self
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPriceWT(): ?float
    {
        return $this->priceWT;
    }

    public function setPriceWT(float $priceWT): self
    {
        $this->priceWT = $priceWT;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        if($this->id)
            return $this->getOrders()->getId()." - ".$this->getProduct()->getName();
        else
            return "";
    }
}
```

And here is the Orders Admin :

```
class OrdersAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->with('label.orders.group1', [
            'class' => 'col-md-6'
        ])
            ->add('internalReference', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.internalReference',
                'required' => true
        ])
            ->add('deliveryDate', DateType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryDate'
            ])
            ->add('comment', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.comment',
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('deliveryContactName', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryContactName'
            ])
            ->add('deliveryContactPhone', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryContactPhone'
            ])
            ->add('status', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.status',
                'choices' => array(
                    'label.orders.statuses.pending' => 1,
                    'label.orders.statuses.confirmed' => 2,
                    'label.orders.statuses.sent' => 3,
                    'label.orders.statuses.cancel' => 4,
                )
            ])
            ->end();
        $formMapper->with('label.orders.group2', [
            'class' => 'col-md-6'
        ])
            ->add('deliveryCompany', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryCompany',
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('deliveryAddress1', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryAddress1'
            ])
            ->add('deliveryAddress2', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryAddress2',
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('deliveryPostalCode', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryPostalCode'
            ])
            ->add('deliveryCity', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryCity'
            ])
            ->add('deliveryCountry', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryCountry'
            ])
            ->end();

        if ($this->isCurrentRoute('edit', 'admin.orders'))
            $formMapper->add('product', OrdersProductType::class, array(
                'order' => $this->getSubject(),
            )
            );

    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $filter)
    {
        $filter->add('internalReference')
            ->add('deliveryCompany');
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $list)
    {
        $list->addIdentifier('id');
        $list->add('dateAdd', 'date', [
            'label' => 'label.orders.dateAdd'
        ]);
    }

    public function prePersist($orders)
    {
        $orders->setdateAdd(new \DateTime());
        $orders->setDateUpd(new \DateTime());

    }

    public function preUpdate($orders)
    {
        $orders->setDateUpd(new \DateTime());
    }

}
```

And the OrdersProductType :

```
class OrdersProductType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('product', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Product::class,
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
        ))
            ->add('quantity')
            ->add('priceWT')
            ->add('orders', HiddenType::class, array(
                'data' => $options['order']
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired(array('order'));
    }
}
```

I tried to use a CollectionType::class with a OrdersProductAdmin, but It is impossible to save the OrdersProduct as I don't know how to pass the Orders id to the embedded form. So, I made a custom form type, but :

When I submit the form, I get the error :

```
Expected value of type "App\Entity\OrdersProduct" for association field "App\Entity\Orders#$product", got "Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Product" instead.
```

If I dump the $orders var in the preupdate function, I have :

```
OrdersAdmin.php on line 121:
OrdersProduct {#1405 ▶}
OrdersAdmin.php on line 121:
OrdersProduct {#1419 ▶}
OrdersAdmin.php on line 121:
Product {#1420 ▶}
OrdersAdmin.php on line 121:
"33"
OrdersAdmin.php on line 121:
"12"
OrdersAdmin.php on line 121:
"1 -SG-000251 wonder"
```

The first 2 OrdersProduct are correct (they are in my DB). But the last 4 items are just not correct ! It should be OrdersProduct, with a Product, a quantity, a price and an order.

Thanks for your help.

Best

Answer (score 0):

I found the (partial, as I have a form issue now !) solution !

Here are the code :

*Orders Class :*

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OrdersRepository")
 */
class Orders
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateAdd;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateUpd;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $deliveryDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $internalReference;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $deliveryContactName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=15)
     */
    private $deliveryContactPhone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $deliveryAddress1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $deliveryAddress2;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $deliveryPostalCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $deliveryCountry;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $deliveryCompany;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $comment;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $deliveryCity;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\OrdersProduct", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="orders")
     */
    private $product;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->product = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDateAdd(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateAdd;
    }

    public function setDateAdd(\DateTimeInterface $dateAdd): self
    {
        $this->dateAdd = $dateAdd;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateUpd(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateUpd;
    }

    public function setDateUpd(\DateTimeInterface $dateUpd): self
    {
        $this->dateUpd = $dateUpd;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->deliveryDate;
    }

    public function setDeliveryDate(\DateTimeInterface $deliveryDate): self
    {
        $this->deliveryDate = $deliveryDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInternalReference(): ?string
    {
        return $this->internalReference;
    }

    public function setInternalReference(?string $internalReference): self
    {
        $this->internalReference = $internalReference;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryContactName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliveryContactName;
    }

    public function setDeliveryContactName(string $deliveryContactName): self
    {
        $this->deliveryContactName = $deliveryContactName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryContactPhone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliveryContactPhone;
    }

    public function setDeliveryContactPhone(string $deliveryContactPhone): self
    {
        $this->deliveryContactPhone = $deliveryContactPhone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryAddress1(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliveryAddress1;
    }

    public function setDeliveryAddress1(string $deliveryAddress1): self
    {
        $this->deliveryAddress1 = $deliveryAddress1;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryAddress2(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliveryAddress2;
    }

    public function setDeliveryAddress2(?string $deliveryAddress2): self
    {
        $this->deliveryAddress2 = $deliveryAddress2;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryPostalCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliveryPostalCode;
    }

    public function setDeliveryPostalCode(string $deliveryPostalCode): self
    {
        $this->deliveryPostalCode = $deliveryPostalCode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryCountry(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliveryCountry;
    }

    public function setDeliveryCountry(string $deliveryCountry): self
    {
        $this->deliveryCountry = $deliveryCountry;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryCompany(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliveryCompany;
    }

    public function setDeliveryCompany(?string $deliveryCompany): self
    {
        $this->deliveryCompany = $deliveryCompany;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?int
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(int $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getComment(): ?string
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }

    public function setComment(?string $comment): self
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryCity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliveryCity;
    }

    public function setDeliveryCity(string $deliveryCity): self
    {
        $this->deliveryCity = $deliveryCity;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
       if ($this->id)
           return $this->id." -".$this->internalReference;
       else
           return "";
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|OrdersProduct[]
     */
    public function getProduct(): Collection
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function addProduct(OrdersProduct $product): self
    {
        if (!$this->product->contains($product)) {
            $this->product[] = $product;
            $product->setOrders($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProduct(OrdersProduct $product): self
    {
        if ($this->product->contains($product)) {
            $this->product->removeElement($product);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($product->getOrders() === $this) {
                $product->setOrders(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function setProduct($products)
    {
        $this->product = $products;
        foreach ($products as $product)
        {
            $product->setOrders($this);
        }
    }

}
```

*OrdersProduct Class :*

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OrdersProductRepository")
 */
class OrdersProduct
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Orders", inversedBy="product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $orders;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $priceWT;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getOrders(): ?Orders
    {
        return $this->orders;
    }

    public function setOrders(?Orders $orders): self
    {
        $this->orders = $orders;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProduct(): ?Product
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function setProduct(?Product $product): self
    {
        $this->product = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuantity(): ?int
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    public function setQuantity(int $quantity): self
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPriceWT(): ?float
    {
        return $this->priceWT;
    }

    public function setPriceWT(float $priceWT): self
    {
        $this->priceWT = $priceWT;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        if($this->id)
            return $this->getOrders()->getId()." - ".$this->getProduct()->getName();
        else
            return "";
    }
}
```

*OrdersAdmin :*

```
class OrdersAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->with('label.orders.group1', [
            'class' => 'col-md-6'
        ])
            ->add('internalReference', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.internalReference',
                'required' => true
        ])
            ->add('deliveryDate', DateType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryDate'
            ])
            ->add('comment', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.comment',
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('deliveryContactName', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryContactName'
            ])
            ->add('deliveryContactPhone', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryContactPhone'
            ])
            ->add('status', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.status',
                'choices' => array(
                    'label.orders.statuses.pending' => 1,
                    'label.orders.statuses.confirmed' => 2,
                    'label.orders.statuses.sent' => 3,
                    'label.orders.statuses.cancel' => 4,
                )
            ])
            ->end();
        $formMapper->with('label.orders.group2', [
            'class' => 'col-md-6'
        ])
            ->add('deliveryCompany', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryCompany',
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('deliveryAddress1', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryAddress1'
            ])
            ->add('deliveryAddress2', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryAddress2',
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('deliveryPostalCode', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryPostalCode'
            ])
            ->add('deliveryCity', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryCity'
            ])
            ->add('deliveryCountry', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.orders.deliveryCountry'
            ])
            ->end();

        if ($this->isCurrentRoute('edit', 'admin.orders'))
            $formMapper->add('product', CollectionType::class, array(
                'by_reference' => false,
            ),
                array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'inline'
                ));

    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $filter)
    {
        $filter->add('internalReference')
            ->add('deliveryCompany');
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $list)
    {
        $list->addIdentifier('id');
        $list->add('dateAdd', 'date', [
            'label' => 'label.orders.dateAdd'
        ]);
    }

    public function prePersist($orders)
    {
        $orders->setdateAdd(new \DateTime());
        $orders->setDateUpd(new \DateTime());

    }

    public function preUpdate($orders)
    {
        $orders->setDateUpd(new \DateTime());
        $orders->setProduct($orders->getProduct());


    }

}
```

*OrdersProductAdmin :*

```
class OrdersProductAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->add('product', EntityType::class, [
            'class'=> 'App\Entity\Product',
            'choice_label' => 'name'
        ])
            ->add('quantity')
            ->add('priceWT')
            ->add('orders', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Orders::class,
                'data' => $this->getRoot()->getSubject()
            ]);
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {

    }

    public function prePersist($objects)
    {
        //$objects->setOrders($this->getRoot()->getSubject());
        //dd($objects);
    }
```

The OrdersProduct form is well displayed (embedded in the other form). I can get the Orders->id in the OrdersProduct Form.

Now, I have another issue : the form doesn't refresh throwing an error 500 !